# SSH Connection reset from some VMs but not from other

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh, openssh

I have some different VMs running RHEL 8.6 with the same configuration and in the same Vnet and Subnet. I also have a Windows 2022 VM, in that same subnet, with OpenSSH installed and sshd service running.

From some of those linux VMs I am able to ssh to the windows server, while from others I'm not. I simply get connection reset, without even getting asked for the password.

What is even weirder is that in one VM, I created multiple docker containers, all using the same image. From some containers I can ssh, and from others, I can't. Even though all traffic is going through the same network interface, and all the containers are made from the same image.

Example of what sshd logs on windows look like when one of the VMs can't connect

[Not Working SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fx1H.png)

Here is what the logs look like when a VM that is able to connect, does so:

[Working SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJPFl.png)

Both running the same command - "ssh user@10.199.23.203"

Comment: Confused…Those logs are from the client or the server?

Comment: @Ramhound both logs from the server on the windows machine, 2 connections coming from 2 different containers running inside the same linux machine